# Cisco 2960: RSTP finished when?

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, cisco-2960, ieee-802.1w

I have several Cisco 2960 switches here, all configured for RSTP.

```
15.0(2)SE6
C2960-LANBASEK9-M

spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
```

Topology is as follows:

```
S1 -- S2 -- S4
  \        /
   \__S3__/
```

I change the bridge ID on S3 so that it will become root bridge.

I then have the following debug output:

```
Apr  7 12:25:27.173: RSTP(1): updt roles, received superior bpdu on Gi0/2
Apr  7 12:25:27.173: RSTP(1): Gi0/1 is now root port
Apr  7 12:25:27.173: RSTP(1): Gi0/2 blocked by re-root
Apr  7 12:25:27.173: RSTP(1): Gi0/2 is now designated
Apr  7 12:25:27.182: STP[1]: Generating TC trap for port GigabitEthernet0/1
Apr  7 12:25:27.182: RSTP(1): updt roles, received superior bpdu on Gi0/1
Apr  7 12:25:27.182: RSTP(1): we become the root bridge
Apr  7 12:25:27.182: RSTP(1): Gi0/1 is now designated
Apr  7 12:25:27.182: RSTP(1): transmitting a proposal on Gi0/2
Apr  7 12:25:27.190: RSTP(1): received an agreement on Gi0/2
Apr  7 12:25:27.199: STP[1]: Generating TC trap for port GigabitEthernet0/2
```

At which point in this log is the RSTP process finished and will start forwarding frames again? My thought is at 27.190, a total of 13 ms. Is this assumption correct or is the last line in the log still part of the RSTP process?

Comment: On which port? I think you mean to ask when the switches have all converged. STP, including RSTP` is an ongoing process. BPDUs are being sent and received all the time. You will begin forwarding on `G0/2` when it becomes a designated port at `12:25:27.173`, and you will begin forwarding on `G0/1` when it becomes a designated port at `12:25:27.182` None of that means the switches on the other end of those links aren't still blocking for a few more milliseconds, which appears to be the case for the switch connected to `G0/2`.

Comment: On both `g0/2` and `g0/1`. `g0/2` becomes designated at `.173`, I am confused about the last line at `.199`. No more debug output is produced afterwards. I have not tried syncing debug output for the other switches.

Comment: The last line looks like it is generating an SNMP trap for the topology change, as does the 5th line.

Comment: That seems to make sense. So actual convergence on S3 would be completed at `.190`? At which point in time the other switches are finished is not relevant right now.

Comment: Convergence is when all the switches agree. You don't have enough information to determine when that happens. S3 thinks it's done at `12:25:27.182` when both its interfaces are correctly set, and it will begin sending traffic on both of them. That doesn't mean that the other switches won't block the traffic until they have finished running the STP algorithm. When all switches have finished, you are converged. Each switch can finish at a different time. Some may be done before S3 (S2 may be done first), and some may be done after S3 (whichever switch is connected to `G0/2` of S3).

Comment: That is not required, knowing when S3 will finish is enough, for now. (I can't say when the other ones finish because I don't have the logs right now)
Why is S3 done at `.182` not at `.190`?

Comment: It is finished when it has placed all its interfaces in the final state. That is when the last interface (`G0/1`) is set to the `designated` state. As soon as that happens, the port starts forwarding traffic.

Comment: I think the part you may be missing is that STP is constantly evaluating which ports should be used. The switches send and receive BPDUs all the time, and the receipt, or lack of receipt, of BPDUs can change how the STP will operate. When a switch receives a superior BPDU, a TCN BPDU, or misses an expected BPDU over a time period, STP will reevaluate, and it may make changes. This is a constant, ongoing process, so it is really never finished. You call it converged when all switches agree on the topology, but it can change at any time.

Comment: Of course it can change any time, but not when nothing changes in the topology or the configuration.
As far as I remember, designated is just the port role. Only the port state "forwarding" will tell if frames are being forwarded on that interface.
Without the proposal/agreement no forwarding state?

Comment: The proposal/agreement is with the other switch. When it agrees to the proposal, it will set its port as a root port and start forwarding. The switch you are looking at will begin forwarding on each port as it gets set to the designated port. That doesn't mean the switches on the other ends of the links are not blocking the traffic.

Comment: Thanks, I used your answer below for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to ask when the switches have all converged. STP, including RSTP` is an ongoing process. BPDUs are being sent and received all the time.

You will begin forwarding on G0/2 when it becomes a designated port at 12:25:27.173, and you will begin forwarding on G0/1 when it becomes a designated port at 12:25:27.182 None of that means the switches on the other end of those links aren't still blocking for a few more milliseconds, which appears to be the case for the switch connected to G0/2.

Without looking at the other switches, you cannot tell when they have all converged, which may take just a little longer than S3. With what you have provided, you can't tell when they are all in agreement.